# I want to use Google Map API for my Desktop application

Tags: java, google-maps

I want to use google map API for my desktop application. The application will be totally connected to the internet.

While I was searching some research notes about this implementation. I found a ideal site with the configurations, but it has some java files to be downloaded, but when I tried that website its not loading. which is swinglabs.org

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html

Any other options of doing this api implementation to my desktop application? and one more thing. I tried downloading the google api. even it ask a url.We have to provide a url then only we get a key to download it. And the api should run in that specific url. Otherwise, its not working. How this appears to a desktop application

any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it is illegal to use the JXMapViewer with google maps, reason being that this component requires direct access to Google's tile server. According to Google's ToC:

> Can I access the Maps and Satellite
> images directly?
>
> You may not access
> the maps or satellite images through
> any mechanism besides the Google Maps
> APIs (such as the creation of your own
> mapping API or the use of a bulk tile
> download script). Your application's
> access to the tiles will be blocked if
> it accesses them outside of the Google
> Maps APIs. See section 5.3 of the
> Google Terms of Use for more details.

More information can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_tiles). You should be able to download the packages from [here](https://swingx.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=6868&expandFolder=6868&folderID=11425). They moved the domain and many sites still point to the old domain, hence taking you nowhere.

Currently the only way you can use the JXMapViewer by displaying maps from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).

You can, however, display static maps on your application. You basically build a URL. This [tutorial](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-maps-without-scripting.html) should give you a basic idea on how to be able to build a URL to be able to request static maps. You then use an HTTP Get request to get the image back.

Last but not least, Google is planning on allowing direct access to their tile servers, but this might take a while.

Comment: thanks for the replies. but my application is a desktop application. so i do need to download google api. but they asking for a URL to get the key. i do need to get the key to download and use it. please is there any other way. 

is there any other tutorials for teaching how to setup google map api with a desktop application

Comment: You need a key to get access to google maps. I posted a link to a tutorial that shows you how to build the URL to get a map from google maps. You can get a static map from Google to display on your desktop application as long as your application can be downloaded for free.

Comment: GMap.Net allows it but not legally.

Comment: @Dasiths: Please remove the comment above.

Comment: Let me rephrase then. It allows it via "scraping" which is against their API terms (but then again they aren't using the API so they aren't bound to the TOS in that). The legality of it can be argued that way to be totally within legality. Certainly the project it self as it doesn't link any source to Google maps. It merely provides tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google maps in desktop applications.

For this you need to embed a browser in your application and then open up html/javascript files which render a map.

Different languages and api provide ways to embed a browser. For example wxwidgets/c++ has a widget called WebView which allows to embed webkit on linux and trident on windows. Similary mfc/c# also allow the same. So checkout how to embed a browser into your application.

The api should also provide a way to execute javascript code in the embedded browser. Then you can modify the google map through the code of the application as and when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a desktop application that calls a similar API. They require the API calls to come from one particular domain (and URL). So, I have the desktop app contact my own web server, which calls the third party API and returns the results.

Comment: if it need a URL how come its a desktop application. so its not a desktop application. my question is for a desktop application

Comment: @Nubkadiya, Do you understand that you can have your desktop application contact your own web server, which then calls the API?

Comment: But you're not displaying maps in the desktop application anymore. You can do it without even needing a web server by using a HTML template and javascript. You just populate the HTML template and open it in the web browser.